# datetime '08-déc-2022 09:02' does not match format '%d-%b-%y %H:%M'

Tags: python, datetime

i try to get obj but i can't please any solution thank you !

```
def check_date(get_date):
        date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime('08-déc-2022 09:02','%d-%b-%y %H:%M')
        print('date object formta',date_obj)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I've noticed is that you need to use `%Y` as it stands for the 4 digits notation of a year (2022), where `%y` is just 2 digits (22)
Another thing, the Month abbreviation has to start with an uppercase letter (`Déc`)

Also, it really depends on your locale, as in mine, I couldn't use `Déc` and had to use `Dec`

You can check your locale via:

```
import locale
locale.getlocale()
```